# Input image not getting read in java with getResource

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm trying to add image of user's selection to my pdf generated through pdfbox in netbeans. If i directly give path to directly then it's working but with getting url of image path and adding that doesn't work.

See the given code problem is with URL and Path, Because input isn't getting read

```java
 public static ByteArrayOutputStream PDFGenerator(........,Path imagespath)
  {
    ........
    if (finalpdf.Images != null)
    {
      Path imagepath = Paths.get(imagespath.toString(), "room.png");
      PDImageXObject Addedimage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagepath.toString(), pdf);
      AddImages(content, Addedimage, 229.14f, 9.36f);
    }

    //AddImages method is following
  public static void AddImages(PDPageContentStream content, PDImageXObject image, float x, float y) throws IOException
  {

    content.drawImage(image, x, y);

  }
}

  //Following is snippet from my test method
  public void testClass()
  {
    ........
    finalpdf.Images = "room.png";
    URL imageurl = testclass.class.getResource("room.png");
    Path imagepath = Paths.get(imageurl.getPath().substring(1));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = PDFGenerator.generatefurtherpdf(finalpdf, "0000.00", "00.00", imagepath);

    writePDF(baos, "YourPdf.pdf");

  }
```

I expect that it works this way but i'm sure its some problem with Path, I'm not using this correctly. I hope the code is explanatory enough as i'm quite new also there are security reasons so I can't put the whole code. Sorry for mistakes

Comment: Switch implemetation to InputStreams as image data feed, not files. Will work both for files and resources then.

Comment: Antonio is right. You can output `imagepath` at runtime to see what's in it. `getResource` returns an URL. This can be a file, but doesn't have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For resources (never a `File`) there exists a generalized class: `Path`.

```
Path path = Paths.get(imageurl.toURI());
```

However whenever that path (for instance with an URL ´jar:file//... .jar!... ... .png") will be used as File, which an `path.toString()` suggests, one can use an InputStream.

The second generalized class is an `InputStream` which is more low-level:

```
InputStream in = TestClass.getResourceAsStream(imagepath);
```

This is a short-cut for the never used `getResource().openStream()`. Throwing a NullPointerException when the resource path is incorrect.

The last ressort is to use the actual `byte[]` for [createFromByteArray](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/graphics/image/PDImageXObject.html#createFromByteArray-org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument-byte:A-java.lang.String-).

```
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(path);
PDImageXObject Addedimage = PDImageXObject.createFromByteArray(doc, bytes, name);
```

---

***Using a temporary file***

```
  Path imagepath2 = Files.createTempFile("room", ".png");
  Files.copy(imagepath, imagepath2);
  PDImageXObject Addedimage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(imagepath2.toString(), pdf);
```

Comment: I'm getting error of cannot find symbol createFromByteArray(doc, bytes, name) i'm quite surprised as i have added all the necessary imports. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: One must first have a [`PDDocument doc`](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html) created to be filled. If the error was on `doc`.

Comment: dcoument is created problem  is even in intellicense, other methods like createFromFile() are showing up but not createFromByteArray()

Comment: That docu gives as version 2.0.11; it is likely a version problem rather than a wrong signature (parameter types), as intellicese did not give anything. Then using a temporary files seems the only solution. Look whether your version does not provide some other means besides File, like InputStream. Though you probably already did.

Comment: version wasn't the problem. I used createFromFileExtension() method instead and converted input stream to file object. This solved the problem. Thanks for suggestions.